# Craft 4 Building a Plugin not saving all properties

Tags: plugin-development, craft4, custom

After following the "How to build a plugin" from the official CraftCMS docs, I've started extending the Control Panel Template from 1 to multiple fields, all are of the same type string and all "fields" use a simple Textfield

Here the Model:

```
class Settings extends Model {
    public $pluginName = 'AgeGate';
    public $isAgeGateEnabled = true;
    public $minimumAgeAllowed = 10;
    public $agegateTitle = 'Age Verification';
    public $agegateContent = 'Verify your age';
    public $dayPlaceHolder = 'DD';
    public $monthPlaceHolder = 'MM';
    public $yearPlaceHolder = 'YYYY';

    public $agreeButtonLabel = 'Enter';
    public $declineButtonLabel = 'Leave';
    public $failureMessage = 'You are not old enough to enter this site';


    public function defineRules(): array {
        return [
        ];
    }
}
```

and here the settings template

```
{% import '_includes/forms.twig' as forms %}

{{ forms.textField({
    first: true,
    label: 'Minimum Age Allowed',
    name: 'minimumAgeAllowed',
    value: settings.minimumAgeAllowed
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Title of Age Gate',
    name: 'agegateTitle',
    value: settings.agegateTitle
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Content of agegate',
    name: 'agegateContent',
    value: settings.agegateContent
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Agree Button',
    name: 'agegateAgreeButton',
    value: settings.agreeButtonLabel
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Decline Button',
    name: 'agegateDeclineButton',
    value: settings.declineButtonLabel
}) }}
```

I don't have any problems saving the first three fields, but when changing the content of the last 2 fields my changes don't get updated.

I just can't see the reason why certain fields get updated and others not. Did anyone had this issue before?

Note: defineRules is empty on purpose for testing as currently i don't care about validating input

Comment: It looks like your input `name` attributes don't quite match your `Settings` model properties. I see `agegateDeclineButton` in the template, but `agreeButtonLabel` in the model; it _does_ seem like the correct properties are being set back on the input for their `value` attributes, though! (i.e. `settings.agreeButtonLabel`)

Comment: I see I see.. so the name and value need to be the same.

Comment: @funkysoul if that ends up fixing it for you, let us know so August can add it as an official answer!

Comment: Hi Brad, yes definitely, Augusts comment was the right answer.

Comment: @AugustMiller you're up!

Comment: Added! Thanks for the ping. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft automatically sets values from the incoming POST data on your `Settings` model, which means the input `name` attributes must match *exactly* (or that the `Settings` model must expose an appropriate “setter” method).

It appears that your class property is `agreeButtonLabel` (not `agegateAgreeButton`), which means that its field’s macro call should look like this:

```
{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Agree Button',
    name: 'agreeButtonLabel',
    value: settings.agreeButtonLabel,
}) }}
```

I suspect this was ultimately just a typo, because you already had the correct property name for the `value` part of the macro!